# How to use Math functions in c with gcc without explicitly linking math library

Tags: c, gcc

I am using C as the language for solving problems on SPOJ.

But (as they use gcc, and almost every online judge) I can't do like

```
#include <math.h>
```

as I will get undefined reference in gcc.
Also I have no option to explicitly link math library using `-lm`  while compiling at SPOJ.

So is there any workaround?

Comment: `Also I have no option to pass command line arguments while compiling at SPOJ.` not getting?

Comment: @Jayesh : To include math functions in gcc, we have to explicitly link math library `-lm`

Comment: Why??? `scanf` and `pointers` will help you to get command line arguments!

Comment: @shekharsuman : Please see the EDITed title and body.

Comment: That's why anciens created `make`...

Comment: "... there is no such header in gcc." -- huh ?

Comment: @PaulR : Sorry , I meant I will get undefined reference. I edited that.

Comment: If they don't let you link with libm then there is probably a good reason for that - maybe you're supposed to solve the problems without resorting to math library functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is something else. The SPOJ compiler flags include -lm.
Reference: http://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=4015#p6674

Answer (score 0):

Consider using C++ instead of C:  the C++ standard library includes those math functions, so you don't need `-lm`.  Just `#include <cmath>`.